# How to you bridge a LAN and a Wireless device on Windows XP by hand?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-mobile, bridging

How to you bridge a LAN and a Wireless device on Windows XP by hand?   Does anyone know how to do it?   I have a situation where XP "Network Connection Sharing" isn't working for me.  I want to try "bridging" like Vista/Windows7 will do (in the networks control panel).   I can do it manually , by hand.  Does anyone know the concept of it, or how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some [bridging instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/hnw_understanding_bridge.mspx?mfr=true) from Microsoft.

Comment: i should have looked harder.  thanks for the answers.  that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Select both connections, right-click, and click Bridge Connections.